# How to disable auto open jquery ui month picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery ui plugin with MonthPicker. https://github.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker. I followed the guide and call the function MonthPicker(). I want to display input only show I add Button: false. But, month picker auto open. How can I solve this problem?

This is my code:

HTML:

```
  <div class="row pt-0 pb-0" title="Add Period" id="modalPeriod">
            <div class="card w-100" style="border-bottom: 0;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4 mt-2">
                            <label for="plan_period" class="m-0">
                                Period (month)(<small class="text-danger">*</small>)
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input type="text" id="plan_period" class="input-sm form-control" value="" readonly>
                            <small class="text-danger" style="display: none;" id="err_period"></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-4 mt-2">
                            <label for="start_date">Start Date (<small class="text-danger">*</small>)</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input type="text" id="start_date" value="" class="input-sm form-control">
                            <small class="text-danger" style="display: none;" id="err_start_date"></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mt-2">
                        <div class="col-4 mt-2">
                            <label for="end_date">End Date (<small class="text-danger">*</small>)</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input type="text" id="end_date" class="input-sm form-control">
                            <small class="text-danger" style="display: none;" id="err_end_date"></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
   let modalPeriod = $('#modalPeriod').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 300,
        buttons: {
            Save: function () {

            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        open: function (event, ui) {
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function () {
                jQuery('#modalPeriod').dialog('close');
            }).css({
                "background": '#212529',
                'opacity': '0.6'
            });
            $('#plan_period').MonthPicker({});
        },
    });
```

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. Do you want `MonthPicker` to open only when `button` is clicked. Or you want to `hide the button`?

Comment: I want to hide button and only click into the input tag.

Comment: As per the document `$('#plan_period').MonthPicker({ Button: false });` will not create `button`. You can try it here http://jsfiddle.net/kidsysco/JeZap/

Comment: Thanks, I know it but the month picker is auto open when I refresh. I wanna fix this :( I dont know why it happen.